# Is it possible to convert string to literal object array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
var vString = "{ "var1":"varA", "var2":"varB", "var3":"varC" }";

var literalArray = vString;

console.log(literalArray["var1"]); // = varA
```

How can string be converted to a literal array?

Comment: That string is syntactically incorrect, and if it weren't it would be the JSON representation of an *object* but not an *array*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work for you...

```js
var string = '{"var1":"varA", "var2":"varB", "var3":"varC" }';
var objectArray = (new Function("return " + string+ ";")());
console.log(objectArray.var1);
```

Comment: Any Cons using this method?

Comment: @CPLUSPLUS, i don't think so,.. this is working for this simple  `string = "0,1,2";` also and it will split the string from comma's `,` only...

Answer (score 2):

Modify your code as given below:

```
var vString = '{ "var1":"varA", "var2":"varB", "var3":"varC" }';

var literalArray = vString;

console.log(JSON.parse(literalArray)["var1"]);
```

Comment: Is it possible without JSON?

Comment: @CPLUSPLUS no. And it's not an array.

Comment: @CPLUSPLUS you may need to write your own parsing function for that. I see no harm in using JSON.parse as it's in-built in javascript.

Comment: If JSON.parse isn't available, `eval` will work, but is considered to be a very bad practice when not necessary.